# Using ng-repeat over the results from a PouchDB promise

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, promise, pouchdb

I have the following code generating some results from a DB:

```
var db = pouchService.db;
db.allDocs({startkey: 'move_', endkey: 'move_\uffff', include_docs: true})
    .then(function (data) {
        $scope.recordlist = data;
        console.log($scope.recordlist);
    });
```

On the front end, I need to display this results (and also some nested properties), using ng-repeat:

```
<div class="row msf-row" 
   ng-repeat="record in recordlist | filter: shouldShow" 
   ng-class="{ 'msf-cancelled': record.cancelled, 'msf-commented' : record.comment}">
       <div class="col-md-1">{{record.time}}</div>
</div>
```

My problem is that the result from the Promise is nested, and not a clean array. Therefore there's no record in recordlist per se.

How could I access it as such?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its really easy like this:

```
<div class="row msf-row" 
   ng-repeat="record in recordlist.rows | filter: shouldShow" 
   ng-class="{ 'msf-cancelled': record.doc.cancelled, 'msf-commented' : record.doc.comment}">
       <div class="col-md-1">{{record.doc.time}}</div>
</div>
```

Your datastructure seems to be really messy tho, consider cleaning it up.

Comment: Hi Kevin! What do you mean? The promise result?

Comment: `in recordlist.rows` can't access it either, as the object in itself is inside `doc`..

Comment: read my code carefully please, i have incorporated the part about `doc` already in the answer.